# How to fix Tcl 'Command not found' error while trying to puts error variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcl, expect

I am trying to execute an 'expect script' ***abc*** from another expect script ***xyz*** and capture its output in a ***$result*** variable. ***abc*** in turn executes an AppleScript whose output is something that is echo'd. In ***abc***, I am trying to handle the scenarios that can be ***expect***-ed from the AppleScript. When the AppleScript returns a positive outcome, I use **exit 0** in ***abc***, otherwise I use an **exit 1** (with the hope that the ***$result*** variable of ***xyz*** can later be checked for the exit status and actions performed based on that status).

I tried using something like

```
set [exec bash -c "expect ~/Documents/bash/abc.sh $node"]
puts $result
```

instead of

```
{ [catch {[exec bash -c "expect ~/Documents/bash/abc.sh $node"]} result] } { 
puts $result
}
```

which seems to work to my need, except that the script exits execution abruptly when ***abc*** exits with an **exit 1**.

This is ***abc***, the script that calls the AppleScript.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# 'my_script' is an Applescript to execute. The output of my_script is going to be 'Already connected : XYZ' OR 'Unexpected error. Try again.' OR 'Connected : XYZ'
# When I say output, I mean it is going to echo something. Precisely, the Applescript has the following commands, onlh one of which is executed at a time, when a certain set of rules are satsfied.
# do shell script "echo Already connected : XYZ"
# do shell script "echo Unexpected error. Try again."
# do shell script "echo Connected : XYZ"
set my_script "~/Documents/bash/my.scpt"
spawn osascript $my_script $prodEnv
expect {
    "Already connected : XYZ" { exit 0 } # If the ouput from the script is 'Already Connected : XYZ', then do nothing but just display it on the Terminal. 
    # This is where my problem begins. When I execute the 'exit 0' command, the intention is that the output from the script i.e., 'Already Connected : XYZ' must be displayed on the Terminal.
    # However, that does happen, just not gracefully. It displays 'inavalid command name "Already Connected : XYZ"'
    "Unexpected error. Try again." { exit 1 }
    # The interesting part is, when the command executed is 'exit 1' like above, it is displayed alright on the Terminal, without the preceding 'invalid command name' that is. 
    # An additional encumbrance is that it also displays 'child process exited abnormally' in the following line.
    "Connected : XYZ" { exit 0 }
    # Again, the output here is 'invalid command name : "Connected : XYZ"'
}
```

This is ***xyz*** which calls ***abc***.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set node [lindex $argv 0];
switch $node {
    "node1" { 
        if { [catch {[exec bash -c "expect ~/Documents/bash/abc.sh $node"]} result] } { 
            # This puts is the source of the problem. When abc.sh exits with an 'exit 0' command, puts displays 'invalid command name'. 
            # However, when abc.sh exits with an 'exit 1' command, the shell can suddenly recognise the command.
            puts "$result"
            # The whole point of using catch is to allow abc.sh to use exit 1
            # Here, I would like to do a check to see if abc.sh exited with a 0 or 1 status using $result. If exit status is 1, exit this script, otherwise continue execution.
        }
    }
    # I have additional cases here.
}
# I have code here that must be executed only when _**abc**_ was not exited with an **exit 1**
```

I call ***xyz*** with

```
expect Documents/bash/xyz.sh mynode
```

I expect

```
puts $result
```

to display exactly what is echo'd from the AppleScript but the actual output is either prepended with an 'invalid command name' (when using **exit 0** in ***abc***) or appended with a 'child process exited abnormally' (when using **exit 1** in ***abc***).

EDIT: The "invalid command name" is not displayed when I try to *puts* some string instead of the ***$result*** variable.

```
puts "How are you able to print this string without problem?"
```

is displayed without a prepended error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
catch {[exec bash -c "expect ~/Documents/bash/abc.sh $node"]} result
```

Tcl with execute the `bash` command, and then, because the `exec` is *inside brackets*, the **output of bash will be executed as a Tcl command**.

Parenthetically, you don't need to involve bash at all:

```
if {[catch {exec expect $env(HOME)/.../abc.exp $node} result] != 0} { ... }
```